Not guessing when tuning neural networks
I have a NN with about 750 inputs (sparsely encoded text, mostly). The output is 1 cell - yes or no, this is of type X.
I can guess all day long on the size and depth of my hidden layers. I hate guessing; it's lame and worse, inefficient.
Will someone offer me guidelines on how to determine appropriate sizes and numbers of hidden layers?

if you really have no prior to encode in the architecture, then usually you start with 2/3 layers of 128 neurons and Adam optimizer, but i'd suggest you to first analyze the data with PCA to understand how uniform it is, and possibly use the first N principal component and some ML model on such subspace
